# What does $* mean in bash scripting?

Tags: bash, scripting

What does `$*` mean in bash scripting?

I tried to search on google for it, but I found only about `$0`, `$1` and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this page:

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#IFSEMPTY

> The behavior of $* and $@ when $IFS is empty depends
>   + on which Bash or sh version being run.
>   It is therefore inadvisable to depend on this "feature" in a script.

Answer (score 10):

From the `man` page:

> `*`      Expands  to the positional parameters, starting from one.  When the expansion occurs within double quotes, it expands to a single
>                 word with the value of each parameter separated by the first character of the IFS special variable.  That is, "`$*`" is  equivalent
>                 to  "`$1`c`$2`c...",  where c is the first character of the value of the IFS variable.  If IFS is unset, the parameters are separated
>                 by spaces.  If IFS is null, the parameters are joined without intervening separators.

So it is equivalent to all the positional parameters, with slightly different semantics depending on whether or not it is in quotes.

Answer (score 4):

It's all the arguments passed to the script, except split by word. You almost always want to use `"$@"` instead. And it's all in the `bash(1)` man page.

Answer (score 4):

Its the list of arguments supplied on the command line to the script .$0 will be the script name.

Answer (score 3):

It's a space separated string of all arguments. For example, if `$1` is "hello" and `$2` is "world", then `$*` is "hello world". (Unless $IFS is set; then it's an $IFS separated string.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use symbolhound search engine to find codes that google will not look for.

For your query [click here](http://symbolhound.com/?q=bash+%24%2a)

Answer (score 0):

If you see `$` in prefix  with anything , it means its a variable. The value of the variable is used.

Example:

```
count=100
echo $count
echo "Count Value = $count"
```

Output of the above script:

```
100
Count Value = 100
```

Comment: Though the statement you make is correct, the question was "What is $* mean?

Answer (score 0):

As an independent command it doesn't have any significance in bash scripting.
But, as per usage in commands, it's used to indicate common operation on files / folders with some common traits.

and with grep used to represent zero or more common traits in a command.

Answer (score -1):

Well,such case when you find number of average or total number.

$# number of argument to pass in the number
$* number of all argument to pass

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).